# Convert or import SSL certificate to java keystore

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

I have a SSL certificate I'm trying to import in a Java keystore in order to switch some old application to SSL. I am unfamiliar with everything Java. I have the .crt, .key and .ca bundle files but not clue what formats they're in.

com.cabundle:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEkjC....
```

com.crt:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGDjCCBPag...
```

com.key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvAIBADANBg.....
```

I've tried following this guide: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35976_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_convert_pem_to_jks.html but I get all sorts of garbage errors I can't make anything out of. I just don't get it.

My java configuration file needs this:

```
# SSL configuration (disabled by default)
# ssl-enabled=true|false
# ssl-key-store=
# ssl-key-store-password=
# ssl-key-store-type=jks
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are PEM format certificates.  Before they can be imported, you must merge them into a PKCS12 format cert

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in com.crt -inkey com.key -out temp.p12 -name com -CAfile com.cabundle -caname root -chain
```

Ensure you assign a password - keytool won't import passwordless PKCS12 files

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass [your-password-here] -destkeypass [your-password-here] -destkeystore out.jks -srckeystore temp.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass password-created-in-last-step -alias whatever
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to import the key in the keystore: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

Comment: see my edit - I thought keytool took PEM natively.  It does not

Comment: what does the "-alias com" part do? should I change "com" back to my domain name? what I have is a wildcard certificate for *.example.com

Comment: alias is the name of the certificate within the keystore.  It can be anything you want

Comment: I assume I have to import the CA certificate and key file as well?

Comment: you'll have to merge key and cert into a pkcs12 cert - gimme a minute to add it to the answer

Comment: Now it's whining that "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <whatever> does not exist", I guess that's because my keystore is empty?

Comment: create a keystore first

Comment: I did, it's empty (32 bytes), doesn't add anything to it

Comment: try `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS -alias com`

Comment: happy to help! :)